# while outer loop is running once?

Tags: java, string

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class extractvalues {
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {       
            try{
                // command line parameter
                FileInputStream fstream = new  FileInputStream("c:/kdd.txt");

                // Get the object of DataInputStream
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                //to Read values 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;


                //Read File Line By Line
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)  
                {
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    String[] splitted=null;     
                    //split the given line into array of words seperated by comma               
                    splitted=strLine.split(",");

                    int i=0;
                    //continue loop till it find "." since everyline contain "." in the end 
                    while(!".".equals(splitted)) 
                    {  
                       //print each string one by one                                                    
                       System.out.println(splitted[i++]);                                  
                    }

                }

                //Close the input stream
                in.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {//Catch exception if any
               System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
```

I am running 2 while loop . First loop will read line by line from .txt file and second while loop will read each string from the line .But when I run the loop it read first line and string and then stop.I don't get where I am getting wrong.I am missing something please help!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your inner `while` loop to this:

```
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(strLine);
    String[] splitted=null;     

    //split the given line into array of words seperated by comma               
    splitted=strLine.split(",");

    for (int i=0; i < splitted.length; ++i ) {
        if (splitted[i].equals("."))
            break;

        //print each string one by one                                                    
        System.out.println(splitted[i]);
    }
}
```

You were referencing the entire array `splitted` instead of accessing elements inside the array, the latter being what you actually wanted to do.

Comment: Its working perfectly  thankyou very much . what was wrong in my code ?

Comment: I will mark will take another 3 min before I am allowed to mark .

Answer (score 0):

ran your code in my local machine and got the exception at this line - ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

```
  System.out.println(splitted[i++]);
```

Comment: He should be iterating over the length of the array to avoid problems like the one you have just discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that **splitted** is an `String#Array` , and you can not compare array like this , using `equals()` method

```
 while(!".".equals(splitted))   ---> This is logically incorrect way !!
```

So Try `forEach` loop and compare each String in Array with `.`

```
for(String temp:splitted){
     if(temp.equals("."))  <-- Using equals for comparing 2 String
        break;
   System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: Actually, his input is in a rather bizarre format if each line ends with ",.", but this is what the question says.  If so, then we can just iterate over the splitted string `length - 1` times without even checking for a period.

Comment: My dataset is KDDcup99

Answer (score 0):

Change your inner while loop to this, and make sure there is no need

```
if (splitted[i].equals("."))
```

since last index of string array **does not have only(.) this have extra character too.**

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
System.out.println(strLine);
String[] splitted=null;     
//split the given line into array of words seperated by comma               
splitted=strLine.split(",");
//continue loop till it find "." since everyline contain "." in the end 
for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++) 
{  
System.out.println(splitted[i++]);                                  
}
}
```